# The name (x) does not exist in the current context? C#

Tags: c#, class, scope

I'm new to C# and have been trying to build a simple text based game with a character class that both enemies and the player will inherit.

I keep receiving the error saying that variables such as "Health, Attack, Defense" etc don't exist in the current context! As far as I'm aware (and what other posts say), this happens when you try to reference a variable outside the scope of the current class but I thought I don't think I'm doing that :c

Sorry if there's any major rookie mistakes here! I've been trying to reference other threads to see if anything could help, and nothing really *broke* it, it didn't fix it either (Like adding `{get; set;}`

errors:

> The name 'Health' does not exist in the current context.

> The name 'Defense' does not exist in the current context.

[image: and so on]

Thank you to everyone in advance!

```
public class Character
    {
        // Basic Stats
        public int Health { get; set; }
        public int Attack { get; set; }
        public int Defense { get; set; }
        public int DodgeChance { get; set; }
        public int CritChance { get; set; }
        public int Zell { get; set; }
        public int Turns { get; set; }
        public List<string> Inventory { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }

public class PlayerCharacter : Character
    {
        // Character Base Stats
        Health = 20;
        Attack = 3;
        Defense = 0;
        DodgeChance = 7;
        CritChance = 5;
        Zell = 0;
        Turns = 2;
    }
```

Comment: You can't have a statement (such as a property assignment) outside of the scope of a method. _When_ do you want to assign this property? During construction of the object?

Comment: Yes I wanted it to be assigned when it was constructed! So I'd have to put it inside of a method? What would be the best way to go about that?

Comment: "Yes I wanted it to be assigned when it was constructed!" Then... put it... in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate items in a class directly. It has to be either a property, or it has to be instantiated in a constructor or a method.

Looking at your class, it is best instantiated from a constructor.

Good luck!  :)

```
public class Character
    {
        // Basic Stats
        public int Health { get; set; }
        public int Attack { get; set; }
        public int Defense { get; set; }
        public int DodgeChance { get; set; }
        public int CritChance { get; set; }
        public int Zell { get; set; }
        public int Turns { get; set; }
        public List<string> Inventory { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }

    public class PlayerCharacter : Character
    {
        public PlayerCharacter()
        {
         // Character Base Stats
         Health = 20;
         Attack = 3;
         Defense = 0;
         DodgeChance = 7;
         CritChance = 5;
         Zell = 0;
         Turns = 2;
        }
    }
```